# Python: How do I quantify the difference between two sets of words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, match

I have a use-case where I have a:

```
search_text = '12 Jim Smith'
```

I have a `list of tuples` from which I need to search the above `search_text` and return matching tuples:

```
In [1742]: l
Out[1742]: 
[(1234, 'Jim Beam'),
 (13, 'Mark Smith'),
 (12, 'Jim Jones'),
 (23, 'Adam Smith'),
 (15, 'Mark Taylor'),
 (123, 'Mark Adam')]
```

I need to return the matching tuples from `l` with a score based on the most relevant search, something like below:

**Expected Output:**

```
In [1698]: ans
Out[1698]: 
{
 (12, 'Jim Jones'):  66, # matches ~66% of the search_text. `12` and `Jim` both match
 (1234, 'Jim Beam'): 55, # matches ~55% of the search_text. `12` from `1234` and `Jim` both match 
 (13, 'Mark Smith'): 33, # matches ~33% of the search_text. `Smith`matches
 (23, 'Adam Smith'): 33, # matches ~33% of the search_text. `Smith`matches
 (123, 'Mark Adam'): 20  # matches ~20 %. Just `12` matches from `123`
}
```

**Note: The `values` in above `dict` are random. They are just showing the percent of match.**

Below is my attempt:

```
In [1745]: l1 = [(str(i[0]), i[1]) for i in l]
In [1746]: m = set()

In [1747]: for i in search_text.split():
      ...:     if i.isnumeric():
      ...:         for item in l1:
      ...:             #print(item[0])
      ...:             if i in item[0]:
      ...:                 print("i is = ", i)
      ...:                 print("numeric part matches", item)
      ...:                 m.add(item)
      ...:     else:
      ...:         for item in l1:
      ...:             if i in item[1]:
      ...:                 print("text matches", item)
      ...:                 m.add(item)
      ...: 

In [1748]: m
Out[1748]: 
{('12', 'Jim Jones'),
 ('123', 'Mark Adam'),
 ('1234', 'Jim Beam'),
 ('13', 'Mark Smith'),
 ('23', 'Adam Smith')}
```

This returns the tuples that match, but I am not sure how to get percentage of relevance of match.

Comment: Are your `search_text` always formed that way? Meaning is it always `"number first_name surname"`?

Comment: What is your criteria for considering two strings to be matching? It may be different for various scenarios. Like in case of names , in case of general phrases, or in cases of large explanations. Then too lets consider your example of names it depends what you give priority the name or surname  (or middle name if there) also are you considering that there may be spelling mistakes like Marry can be misspelled as Merry, etc also you here you give priority to number of the name? Please provide some details about the criteria!

Comment: @Camaendir Not necessarily. It can be in any order.

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee I just want to match every substring in `search_text` to every `tuple` in the `list`.  For now we can safely ignore spell checks and similar stuff.

Comment: `12` out of `1234` counts 22% and `12` out of `123` counts 20%...? And the number and words (space separated) are equally counted?

Comment: Then something simple would be tokenizing the strings and numbers as words or chunks separated by a delimiter and do a nested loop to check for match and calculate percentage of match. But for a finer quality i would surely suggest you to try with AI as there it would be lot better but still it depends on the situation you want to deploy

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Please don't go with the actual % numbers. I've just put them as sample. It just denotes the relevance of the match. I've added a `Note` in my question stating the same.

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee For now, I just want to write a function that suffices this. It may not be 100% effective as an AI-based solution.

Comment: Something like `difflib` maybe helpful here?

Comment: Why don't you just match against each and calculate relevance then sorting...? Aren't `if`, `else` and `for` are reversed?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Yes, have tried that. Can you please tell me how to do it better? Maybe you can post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a way I would do it:

```py
search_text = "12 Jim smith"

results = {}

for item in l:
    percentage = 0
    percentage_increment = 100/(1 + len(item[1].split(" ")))
    for elm in set(search_text.split(" ")):
        if elm.isnumeric():
            if elm in str(item[0]):
                percentage += percentage_increment * len(elm) / len(str(item[0]))
        else:
            if elm in item[1]:
                percentage += percentage_increment
    results[item] = percentage
```

You need to check the percentage calculation dependent on if your list can be formed other than specified in your question. You can leave out the `set` if you can ensure, that `search_text` doesn't contain names multiple times.

Im doing that based on the assumption, that e.g. `13` and `1234` don't match at all.

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct. +1.  `search_text` will not have same name multiple times. Also, `13` and `1234` do not match at all. Will this work if `search_text` contains string first, then integer, or just contain strings or just integers?

Comment: This is about what I would do too. Maybe add a check `if percentage:` before adding to result.

Comment: I wouldn't add an if, because you still want the 0 percentage items in your result. But that depends on how you want your output to be formed.

Comment: @Camaendir This seems to work well for my case. Can you please add some explanation around your code? Would help me a lot.

Comment: Sure. First initerate over every item in the list and calculate a percentage_increment. That’s just 100 divided by the amount of names and numbers inside the tuple (because I want to increment by that amount for every match). Then I iterate over every word in the search text. If it is numeric i check wether the item number matches to it and increment the overall percentage by (percentage_increment * matching_numbers / total numbers). If it’s not numeric I just check wether the item contains this word as a substring and increment the percentage if so. At the end I just save everything.

Comment: To check wether a number contains another number I just convert both to a string and do the same on strings using the in operator. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution :

```
class TextMatch:
    def getAppended(self, items, delimeter=""):#Function to merge all the elements of the tuples to a string to search from
        str_res = ""
        for item in items:
            str_res = str_res + str(item) + delimeter
        return str_res

    def sortTuple(self, tup):#not very important just to sort the result so that the item with maximum match is at the top
        lst = len(tup)  
        for i in range(0, lst):  
            for j in range(0, lst-i-1):
                if (tup[j][0] < tup[j + 1][0]):  
                    temp = tup[j]  
                    tup[j]= tup[j + 1]  
                    tup[j + 1]= temp  
        return tup  

    def search(self, search_text, list_to_search):#main search alggorithm
        search_text_tokens = search_text.split(' ')#splitup search term into tokens or words
        res_list = []
        for item in l:
            match_nums = 0
            for token in search_text_tokens:#checks for the occurrence of the tokens in each element of the tuple
                if token in self.getAppended(item):
                    match_nums = match_nums + len(token)#add the length of matched characters
            res_list.append( (match_nums*100/len(self.getAppended(item)) , item) ) #find percentage of characters matching for that particular case
        return self.sortTuple(res_list)
        

search_text = '12 Jim Smith'

l = [(1234, 'Jim Beam'),  (13, 'Mark Smith'),  (12, 'Jim Jones'), (23, 'Adam Smith'), (15, 'Mark Taylor'), (123, 'Mark Adam')]

matcher = TextMatch()

print("Result is :")
for item in matcher.search(search_text, l):
    print(item)
```

**Output:**

```
Result is :
(45.45454545454545, (12, 'Jim Jones'))
(41.666666666666664, (1234, 'Jim Beam'))
(41.666666666666664, (13, 'Mark Smith'))
(41.666666666666664, (23, 'Adam Smith'))
(16.666666666666668, (123, 'Mark Adam'))
(0.0, (15, 'Mark Taylor'))
```

Comment: Thanks. +1. Can you please also add some explanation around your code for my understanding?

Comment: @MayankPorwal i add some explaination in the comments

Answer (score -1):

```
m = []
for item in l1:
    a, n = 0, 0
    for i in search_text.split():
        if i.isnumeric():
            if i in item[0]:
                a += 1
            n += 1
        else:
            if i in item[1]:
                a += 1
            n += 1
    m.append((item, 1.0 * a / n))

m.sort(key=lambda item: -item[1])
for item in m:
    print(item)
```

Aren't search engines usually working in this way? Matching for each and sorting.

Comment: Which one...? Usually they use something like BM25 base on vectorization.

Comment: Am I missing something important here...?